# Мне нужно отсортировать список в порядке убывания. Везде написано сделать так какой у меня код, но он всё равно сортирует неправильно, почему?

Tags: python

Вот кодик
Если вводить список так 3 4 5 6 2, то выводит правильно. но если в писке двузначные числа, то неправильно, например:
Ввод: 3 5 2 7 10 4
вывод:  ['7', '5', '4', '3', '2', '10']

```
A = input().split()
A.sort(reverse=True)
print(A)
```

Comment: Ты хочешь сортировать числа, а сортируешь строки. И для чего у тебя n?

Comment: извините случайно n добавил

Comment: а как цифры тогда сортировать

Comment: помогите пожалуйста

Comment: умоляю подскажите мне, я честно не понимаю

Comment: `A = [int(v) for v in input().split()]`

Comment: Надо просто самому внимательно прочитать документацию и задать вопрос о том, что именно непонятно. Здесь надо понять: что такое список, что такое строка, и какие у них есть методы. Вот ссылки:<https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/ispolzovanie-spiskov-list-python/> и <https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/operatsii-tekstovymi-strokami-str-python/> Успеха!

Comment: И советую не копировать решение  в комментарии, а самому разобраться. Иначе потом еще труднее будет.

Comment: Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA cпасибо вам огромное